# Firefox IE tab does not include firefox's spelling correction

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, internet-explorer, spell-check, ietab

Is there a good Firefox plug-in which embeds Internet Explorer in a tab yet includes Firefox functionality like the built-in spell checker to underline in red misspelled words?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, because when IETab is running, Internet Explorer is handling the content of the tab, not Firefox.

The only way is to install an addon to Internet Explorer that does spell checking, like [**ieSpell**](http://www.iespell.com/) or the one included in [**IE7Pro**](http://www.ie7pro.com/) for instance. This spell checker will be active when a tab using IETab (and thus IE) is open.